Tauri getCurrentWindow() stops web view from working and app stops refreshing
I am using the following Tauri Verisons:
"@tauri-apps/api": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
"@tauri-apps/cli": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
When I use getCurrentWindow() in a React TSX component, I get the following error in a browser tab page:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'metadata') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'metadata') at getCurrentWindow
The components all appear in the app that opens, however but when I edit something (such as text), the components do not refresh and I have to right click refresh.
This happens on a Mac running macOS Sonoma 14.5 if that makes a difference.
Thanks in advance

I fixed this error by putting the getCurrentWindow() inside a useEffect like this:
const [appWindow, setAppWindow] = useState<Window | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchWindow() {
      const window = await getCurrentWindow();
      setAppWindow(window);
    }

    fetchWindow();
  }, []);

